# how do I know if a flashdrive has formatting for FAT32?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

what size flashdrive do I need for my freeview?  I brought a 8 gb and it not working, is that too small? Information I have found says it needs FAT32. How do I know if a flashdrive has that option?

Comment: You need to simply format the flash drive to FAT32. Plug it to any Windows machine and you should be able to format it to FAT32. Whether it is too small or not, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Plug the flash drive into a Windows PC then right click on My Computer and left click on Manage. Left click on Manage Drives and you will see the flash drive listed. It will show if it is formatted as FAT32 or NTFS. Almost flash drives are formatted FAT32 when purchased new.